# Codeigniter Controller and methods not working without index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

Tried all the possible solutions listed on Stackoverflow - but didn't work. Would love some help here.

Have an application that runs as follows:

localhost/bdl

Have Made the Default controller as 'Measurements'

Now I am making a call to a method within the Measurements controller called measurement_add and I get a 404 .
If I call it using localhost/bdl/index.php/measurements/measurement_add - it works - but not otherwise.

My .htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ /bdl/index.php/page/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bdl/index.php/$1 [L]
```

My httpd.conf file is :

```
AllowOverride All
```

and uncommented the:
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you changed `$config['index_page'] =''` like this in config.php?

Comment: it is better to create a new .htaccess file directly into the folder instead of copy paste from somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

please use this below code in your .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
```

and use below code in your config file
$config['index_page'] =''

Answer (score 0):

first check mod_rewrite is enabled in your apache using phpinfo() function.

Inside your httpd.conf do below change

Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all

In your config.php file set 
$config['index_page'] =''

add below code in .htaccess at the root of your application.

```
RewriteEngine on
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|MobileSiteImage|robots\.txt|flash)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```